# What's the difference between Kone[+] and Kone XTD?

Tags: mouse

As far as I read from the ROCCAT website, the only difference between the [ROCCAT Kone[+]](http://www.roccat.org/Products/Gaming-Mice/ROCCAT-Kone-/) and the [Roccat Kone XTD](http://www.roccat.org/Products/Gaming-Mice/ROCCAT-Kone-XTD/) is the dpi (6000 vs 8000), yet there's a big price difference where I live ($63 versus $105).

Is the Kone XTD just overpriced, or is there a significant difference I am missing?

Comment: You also have different weights, system requirements (windows 8 only on XTD), languages, etc.

Comment: @Batophobia: Both have 4*5g weights, and weight about the same.
i don't relly care about the languages (need only english)
There are drivers for both win7 and 8 (i am using win 7), so is there any sagnificant change other than these?

Comment: I'm not seeing a significant price difference on Amazon between new Kone[+] and new Kone XTD, unless one considers $1.50 (sale) or $10 (list) significant.

Comment: at my countrey xtd costs about 105$, and the cone[+] costs ~63$...
So you suggest buying the [+] rather than the xtd?
@SevenSidedDie

Comment: @Mickey I'm only saying that the price difference you're seeing has more to do with the people/company you're considering buying from than any actual difference in the price that Roccat is selling them for. It's entirely possible that supply and demand differences are more relevant than actual hardware differences.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie: is the shape and size of the [+] the same as the size and shape of the xtd, and are they both palm grip?

Comment: @JeffreyLin We actually do accept some hardware questions, though usually we limit it to gaming-specific hardware.  http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/257/42984

Comment: @JeffreyLin - on our [about](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/about) page, we accept questions about gaming-specific hardware

Comment: anyone can answer please??

Comment: can any one answer me about the difference between roccat [+] ROC-11-800 and the ROC-11-801 version??

Comment: You've already got the a answer in your question -- the sensitivity is higher.

Answer (score 1):

The shape is different, cable is braided, new R3 8200 dpi sensor,larger size, and heavier